# Survivor function for log logistic from survreg output

Tags: r, logistic, survival, nonparametric, kaplan-meier

I am trying to plot/generate a survival curve in Excel using the output from survreg in R. The below is a snapshot from R, I am not sure what to do with the values, how do I convert to the two parameters, θ and k. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

[image]

ps. I am at Step 5 - formula provided for Weibull to calculate lambda and gamma but not for the other functions https://mbounthavong.com/blog/2018/3/15/generating-survival-curves-from-study-data-an-application-for-markov-models-part-1-of-2

```
> model <- survreg(Surv(times_start, times_end, type="interval2")~1, dist="loglogistic")
> model
Call:
survreg(formula = Surv(times_start, times_end, type = "interval2") ~ 
    1, dist = "loglogistic")

Coefficients:
(Intercept) 
   2.645461 

Scale= 0.6496663 

Loglik(model)= -495.2   Loglik(intercept only)= -495.2
n= 225
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Survivor function of Log-Logistic distribution is  $s(t) = \frac{1}{(1+(\alpha t)^\gamma)}$. In `R`, $\alpha=exp(-\frac{Intercept}{Scale})$ and $\gamma = \frac{1}{Scale}$. Intercept and scale are estimated in the `survreg` function in `R`. Please note $\theta$ in your case is $-\frac{Intercept}{Scale}$ and $k$ is $\frac{1}{Scale}$ which is also $\gamma$ in the equation above.

Below is screenshot of how this would be in excel.[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved it!